# Circle CI deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, circleci

I'm trying to setup automatic deploy of a rails app from circle CI to heroku. The problem I'm facing is that I have some files besides database.yml that need to be pushed, for example I have a facebook.sample.yml that needs to be copied into facebook.yml before deploying. One thing to note is that I have on .gitignore facebook.yml (this is in order to keep credentials hidden from the repo)

I used this command to run tests on the settings > test > test command `cp facebook.sample.yml facebook.yml` however, seems circle ci is not pushing that copied file to heroku.

Is there anything else I have to do in order for those files to work? how can I configure my circle ci to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You should move your config data into [Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You may also want to consider using something like [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) to make your config data available to all of your instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says the way to configure Heroku is by using config vars, there's no way to it by copying yml files. So I changed configuration to support both methods